# Users are not getting created in sqlite, how can I debug the connection from rails to sqlite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

When I try to create a user in my dashboard app, nothing really happens. The page refreshes `else, render 'new'` due to failure I think. I don't get any errors, but my user is not getting created. I do get this info in the log though, it appers that it is trying to create the user. How can I trouble shoot sqlite to see why the user is not being created?

```
Started POST "/dashboard_users_index" for 172.16.1.29 at 2014-02-16 13:09:50 -0500
Processing by DashboardUsersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"M9wVDyde4qbYzl517BwMTAqEti0Ju2WtrhX1bh1UGS4=", "dashboard_users"=>{"email"=>"my_user@domain.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create Dashboard users"}
Geokit is using the domain: logmon
  Rendered dashboard_users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 27.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Dashboard Users Controller:

```
class DashboardUsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUsers.new
  end

  def create
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUsers.new(params[:dashboard_user])
    if @dashboard_user.save
      redirect_to 'csdashboard/index', :notice => 'Signed up!'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Dashboard Users Model:

```
class DashboardUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password_hash, :password_salt
  attr_accessor :password

  validates :password, :presence => true,
            :confirmation => true

  validates :email, :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => true

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    dashboard_user = find_by_email(email)
    if dashboard_user && dashboard_user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, dashboard_user.password_salt)
      dashboard_user
    else
      nil?
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash =BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

end
```

Dashboard Users /new.html.rb:

```
<h1>Create a user</h1>

<%= form_for @dashboard_user do |f|%>
    <% if @dashboard_user.errors.any? %>
     <div class="alert-error">
       <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
       <ul>
         <% for message in @dashboard_user.full_message %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
    <% end %>

        <p>
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </p>

        <p>
          <%= f.label :password %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password %>
        </p>

         <p>
           <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
           <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
         </p>
    <p class='button'><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Also, here is my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140215195045) do

  create_table "dashboard_users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_hash"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model names are singular .

Change the class name to DashboardUser like

```
class DashboardUser < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and the file name should be  `dashboard_user.rb`  insted of  `dashboard_users.rb`

The table name should be plural like dashboard_users

In your controller change

```
def new
  @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new
end

def create
  @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new(dashboard_user_params)
  if @dashboard_user.save
     redirect_to dashboard_path , :notice => 'Signed up!'
  else
   render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to debug the connection between Rails and SQLite. You can either print a log or much better to insert a breakpoint to debug your code.

I recommend you to use a powerful debugger like PRY
https://github.com/pry/pry

You can put a debug breakpoint `binding.pry` to see what is happening

```
  def create
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUsers.new(params[:dashboard_user])
    binding.pry
    if @dashboard_user.save
      redirect_to 'csdashboard/index', :notice => 'Signed up!'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Then when making a POST to this action, the executing will stop in this breakpoint, and you can see what is going on with the @dashboard_users

```
> @dashboard_users.save! # with the ! will show the error
> @dashboard_users.valid? # false
> @dashboard_users.errors # returns the errors
> @dashboard_users.errors.full_messages # errors in a clear text
> etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it intentional that you named the model DashboardUsers?

Either try renaming everything in the app from "DashboardUsers" into "DashboardUser".
The resource is called dashboard_users but the model is singular.

Or try at first if it works if you apply the naming convention to this line:

```
class DashboardUsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUsers.new
  end

  def create
    # here is a typo, in the params hash in the log the name is different
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUsers.new(params[:dashboard_users])

    if @dashboard_user.save
      redirect_to 'csdashboard/index', :notice => 'Signed up!'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

But in general. At first try to apply the Rails way as recommended in the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) or any other Rails Tutorial Resource/ Book.

Comment: very good answer by @Rafa ... also notice that because you want to fetch a non-existing key from your params hash it returns nil. Because you have validations on your model the behaviour is works-as-intended. So the new-template is rendered correctly.