# Saving records with has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have two models - users and keywords and a third model associations that connects users and keywords with a has_many through relationship.

I have a create method in keyword controller that is shown below -

```
def create
  @keyword = Keyword.new(keyword_params)
  if Keyword.find_by(content: params[:content]).nil?
    @keyword.save
  end

  @keyword.associations.create(:user_id => current_user.id)
  flash[:success] = "Keyword successfully created!"
  redirect_to keywords_path
```

In the "create" method mentioned above, after a user adds a keyword, I am checking if that keyword already exists in the keywords table and if it doesn't, it saves the keyword in the keywords table and then it saves the association between user and keyword in the associations table.

However, when a keyword already exists in the keywords table (since it might have been added by another user), and lets say a new user is adding this existing keyword to his list, it gives me the error - "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved" at the @keyword.associations.create line since the @keyword.save is skipped (as the keyword already exists in the database).

I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0.0

I am new to Rails and would appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Update:
Adding the details of Keyword model and Keywords controller

Models:
  User model:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
      before_create :create_remember_token

      has_many :associations
      has_many :keywords, :through => :associations

      #name
      validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    end
```

Keyword model:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :associations
  has_many :users, :through => :associations
  validates :content, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Associations model

```
 class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :keyword
      belongs_to :user
      validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :keyword_id }
    end
```

Keywords Controller:

```
class KeywordsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @keywords = current_user.keywords.to_a
  end

  def new
    @keyword = Keyword.new
  end

  def create
    @keyword = Keyword.find_by(content: params[:content])
    if @keyword.nil?
      @keyword = Keyword.create(keyword_params)
    end

    @keyword.associations.create(:user_id => current_user.id)
    flash[:success] = "Keyword successfully created!"
    redirect_to keywords_path
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def keyword_params
      params.require(:keyword).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this works, but when I change

`@keyword = Keyword.find_by(content: params[:content])` to

`@keyword = Keyword.find_by(keyword_params)`, it works.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in the case when the Keyword is found you still refer to the Keyword.new object, which is not the one in db.

You could rewrite it like so:

```
def create
  @keyword = Keyword.find_by(content: params[:content])
  if @keyword.nil?
    @keyword = Keyword.create(keyword_params)
  end

  @keyword.associations.create(:user_id => current_user.id)
  flash[:success] = "Keyword successfully created!"
  redirect_to keywords_path
```

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy for your prompt reponse. Unfortunately, your proposed changes give the same error - "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved"

Comment: it could be because parent has some validation errors, it would help if you inserted the contents of Keyword class

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, I added the code for keywords model & controller in my original question. Please let me know if there is any problem with my validation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can't say a lot now, just add bang to create method, like Keyword.create!(keyword_params). this way you would see if there was validating errors when rails tried to create Keyword, probably there would be some

Comment: Unfortunately same error. If I create a completely new keyword which does not exist using a user's account, it creates successfully with the right association. But if I try adding a keyword already existing in the database (since added by other user), it gives this error irrespective of if I use create or create!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you are calling create in the association model (through table) instead of the user one. Rails should care about the association model not you, so just try to replace

```
@keyword.associations.create(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

by

```
@keyword.users.create(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

If none of this works, I recommend you put a breakpoint in your controller before the create instruction and you have to see what is going on. Check out one of my recents comments about how to debug with PRY https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815636/2793607

Comment: Thanks Rafa. I want unique keywords in the keyword table, but the same keyword can be added by multiple users and it will be stored in the associations table. For example, I have user 1 and user 2 in my users table and keyword 1 and keyword 2 as unique records in my keywords table. Now both users, user 1 and user 2 can have the same keyword - "keyword 1" in their list and this will be reflected in the associations table. So uniqueness true for keywords should work. I don't want "keyword 1" to be stored twice in keywords table.

Comment: I have added code for all models - users, keywords and associations

Comment: Which error are you getting now? Print the exact text.

Comment: I have not removed uniqueness validation from the keyword model since its correct as I want to save only unique keywords and not the same keyword everytime a different user adds the same keyword to their lists. The error I am getting is this - "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved"

Comment: I understand. I think the problem is trying to create in the association model (through) instead of the user one. Rails should care about the association model so just replace `@keyword.associations.create(:user_id => current_user.id)` by `@keyword.users.create(:user_id => current_user.id)`

Comment: Unfortunately the same error - "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved". However, when I try this on rails console, it works fine. So I think there has to be a problem in my create method rather than the model.

Comment: Assigning the same keyword to two users works in the console, but not through my controller. This is what I tried in rails console:

u1 = User.find_by(email: "example-3@railstutorial.org");
u2 = User.find_by(email: "example-4@railstutorial.org");

k1 = Keyword.new;
k1.content = “Pirates”;
k1.save;

u1.keywords << k1;
u2.keywords << k1

This works in rails console but if I use the same in the keywords_controller -> create method, it doesn’t. It gives me the error - “Content is already taken”, since I guess its trying to put Pirates keyword again in the keyword table.